# Recycle bitmaps used in XML layouts

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, eclipse-memory-analyzer

i am using single XML file to show app's **SplashScreen** and **MainActivity**...
**SplashScreen** has images that are causing memory heap to grow up (tested using **Memory Analyser**)...
currently i set visibility of the splashScreen to "Gone"...
also tried removing **splashScreen** layout from XML like `parent.removeChild(splashScreen);` but no effect on memory heap.

Can someone help with recycling the bitmaps in XML *or* i am to use other activity for **splashScreen** *or* create **splashScreen Layout** through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was updating some old source that had such scenario.. well i'm to go with the options as i said-

> *i am to use other activity for splashScreen*

to manage memeory

Comment: can you elaborate you answer? I don't understand nothing

Comment: don't create heavy layouts..and dont put large bitmaps in them..simple.

Answer (score 0):

Make the SplashScreen a separate Activity, set the images in it through XML, android is quite efficient loading and disposing the resources, and just finish the activity when you navigate to your home activity

Or you can load the images manually in code and recycle them after your splash is  hidden and will no longer appear to the user.

Comment: Thanks but i know other options. So you mean to say XML bitmaps cannot be freed up.

Comment: Sure it can, but that's up to Android to free them when it knows that it's not gonna use need them any more, But why have a layout with large bitmap just hidden and not showing ..

Comment: "But why have a layout with large bitmap just hidden and not showing" +1

Comment: it was an old code.. but how it knows (as you said) about XML res needed no more before onDestroy().

Comment: it doesn't, it can't recycle the images unless the view is destroyed, because at any time you can show them again, which is why having the images hidden isn't a very good idea, you can try setting the imageviews holding the image to have null drawables, dunno how much would that help

Comment: as in question..i did set null to the layout containing splashScreen part..nothing changed..

Comment: Yea, that's why i said i dunno if it would help :)